# UI for xamarin android is different from xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have created a UI using Xamarin Forms as follows for both iOS and Android.

```
recordButton.Image = recorderImageViewName;
recordButton.WidthRequest = recordButton.HeightRequest = recorderButtonSize;
var relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();
relativeLayout.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
relativeLayout.Children.Add(recordButton, yConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent =>
         {
            return parent.Height - recorderButtonSize - imageViewPadding;
         }),
            xConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent =>
         {
            return parent.Width / 2 - recorderButtonSize / 2;
         }));
Content = relativeLayout;
```

But the results on android is not as expected, in iOS it's fine.

This is android screenshot
[image: android screenshot]

And this is iOS screenshot
[image: iOS screenshot]

Why is it's so?

Comment: Do you mean the recorderButton.Image? If so, make sure the image is in the right folder for Android (YourProject.Android\Resources\drawable)

Comment: Do your images on Android and iOS have the same dimensions (recorderButtonSize)? Are they located in platforms' folders or in PCL? The appearance can be affected by pixel density.What is the type of recordButton?

Comment: The issue was with the button image aspect. In iOS the image on button is set as aspect fit but in android it's aspect fil. So the image get trimmed in android. So I changed the button to Image and added tap gesture.